# How do I make my AJAX content crawlable by Google?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, web-crawler, htmlunit

I've been working on a site that uses jQuery heavily and loads in content via AJAX like so:

```
$('#newPageWrapper').load(newPath + ' .pageWrapper', function() {
    //on load logic
}
```

It has now come to my attention that Google won't index any dynamically loaded content via Javascript and so I've been looking for a solution to the problem.

I've read through Google's [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html) document what seems like 100 times and I still don't understand how to implement it (due in the most part to my limited knowledge of servers).

So my first question would be:

- Is there a decent step-by-step tutorial out there that documents this from start to finish that you know of? I've tried to Google it and I'm not finding anything useful.

And secondly, if there isn't anything out there yet, would anyone be able to explain:

1. How to 'Set up my server to handle
   requests for URLs that contain
   _escaped_fragment_'
2. How to implement [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) on
   my server to create an 'HTML
   snapshot' of the page to show to the
   crawler.

I would be incredibly grateful if someone could shed some light on this for me, thanks in advance!

-Ben

Comment: Make the site function without Javascript first and then add the Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find an alternative so I took epascarello's advice and now I'm generating the content with php if the URL includes '_escaped_fragment_' (the URL will include that if a crawler visits)

For those searching:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['_escaped_fragment_'])){

        $newID = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];

        //Generate page here
    }

?>
```

Comment: make sure you sanitize $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'] before using it inside of PHP or a DB transaction. Wouldn't want a PHP vulnerability or a SQL injection.

Comment: Handling `_escape_fragment` is indeed the way to go, and I would suggest accepting this answer, even if it's your own. BTW, here is an excellent and modern tutorial on [making AngularJS applications crawlable](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html_.

Comment: With modern day browsers, the solution should be use restful Urls using HTML5 pushState. That whole escape fragment seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to make a site that works with and without JavaScript. Read articles on Progressive enhancement.

Comment: While this is indeed the best solution, it's not generally applicable, and doesn't actually answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

These days this problem is typically solved by using a service that plugs an implementation of Google's scheme for [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html) in at web server level. You don't have to do it yourself any more.

I work for one of these companies: https://ajaxsnapshots.com (there are others)