# Do I need a VPS or can a shared server be used for an Ajax crawlable website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, hosting

I'm hosting a website on a 1&1 shared server, and I need my ajax loaded content to be crawlable by google bots... The site is "hash-bang" ready but now I'm struggling with the escaped_fragment part.
I have to install HtmlUnit, Node.js or Zombie.js to help google deal with my javascript events.

Now I don't understand WHERE to install this piece of software on the server?

While I'm gathering infos, I'm realizing that I'll maybe have to host it on a virtual server (VPS) the be able to access the root or install libraries... Am I right?

I'm not really pleased by the idea of tripling my annual hosting fee just to help google find the my content... Do you know how to achieve crawlable ajax on a shared hosting?

If not, is there a way to host those libraries somewhere else while keeping the site where it is now?

I'm in search of practical infos since google isn't helping much with this, and online articles don't get really into the hosting part. Thx for your help!

Comment: Why do you *need* Node for this? Is your site simply written in Node? Then yes, you need a host that supports whatever you require server-side. That may be shared or may be a VPS.

Comment: Isn't it capable of headless browsing? Well my site is a Wordpress (so PHP) the ajax loads articles.

Comment: Yes, but so what? You want Google to index your hash-bang URLs. Nothing about this requires your server to be a headless browser. It just requires your server to respond to certain URLs with certain content. Something any webserver does.

Comment: I thought headless browser was essential to make this work since it while read and handle the javascript for Google. So do you mean that I only have to put my hash-bang URLs on the sitemap?

Comment: No, headless browsing has nothing to do with hash-bang URLs. You may want to read more about what you're talking about. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html, http://www.w3.org/QA/2011/05/hash_uris.html

Comment: I realized that the above blog posts suggests a headless browser. That's not *necessary* though. All you need is for your web server to return indexable HTML for certain URLs. How those are generated is irrelevant.

Comment: Haha thanks, this is the part I'm stuck into. How to return this Html since it's loaded with ajax and google doesn't handle javascript? It's getting too technical to me. :)

Comment: Well, read the above again. The `#!` informal standard defines a way how a search engine can request a regular URL instead of a `#!` URL. From there it's just regular URLs...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you serve blog posts via ajax with hashbang URLs. Then the only thing you need to do for crawling support is to process URLs with `_escaped_fragment_=work-stuff` in a way that they return in HTML form the same content as it would return via AJAX from corresponding hashbang URLs `#!work-stuff`.

Comment: Yes Stan you're right, but I don't know how to do that... If I understand it correctly, that's where the headless browser comes into play, right? If so then I'm stuck since I use a shared hosting.
Here is my website if you want to see how it works and how posts are indexed by google. http://www.youpiemonday.com/

Comment: I've posted an answer. BTW, you site outputs "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."

Comment: Thx I noticed the `headers already sent by...` but the pages aren't supposed to be seen once google indexes `#!` urls instead of older ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you serve blog posts via AJAX with hashbang URLs. Then the only thing you need to do for crawling support is to process URLs with `_escaped_fragment_=work-stuff` in a way that they return in HTML form the same content as it would return via AJAX from corresponding hashbang URLs `#!work-stuff`.

For example, lets take the following URL from you site as example: `http://www.youpiemonday.com/#!arcena`. When browser navigates here, it receives data from the following "ugly" URL: `http://www.youpiemonday.com/arcena/?_=1355151916735`. I think what would be sufficient to do is to process URLs, generated by crawlers, such as `http://www.youpiemonday.com/?_escaped_fragment_=arcena`, and map them to the same content you return for "ugly" URLs. This way you'll provide main content for indexing.

As for a headless browser, it would be required if your pages are built from data received by many small AJAX requests, and a whole page representation (its main content) does not exists at server at all. Then you could use a headless browser to "browse" such pages yourself and store resulting page snapshots in some cache, from where a crawler could get the plain-html version.

To me, after looking at the site, the answer is no - you do not need VPS.

Comment: Ok I think I see, but how do you process/map URLs? With PHP? I'm not in my comfort zone... :)

For the headless browser part, I'd love to be able to do without it!! But since the click event is handled by javascript, the google crawlers won't be stuck at the gallery level (i.e. not able to see the content of each post)?

Comment: @wyem, I forgot to mention, you should use a sitemap, of course.

Comment: @wyem, as for processing URLs, if you provide some code/details about how you did current hashbang URL processing, this would be the best part of escaped URLs processing. I suppose you can somehow add an escaped alias for every hashbang URL. WordPress seems having plugins for this.

Comment: Ok here is a jsfiddle with the code I use to modify simple URLs into `#!`. http://jsfiddle.net/rRnUD/ I commented `FIRST and SECOND part of the hash change` the two paragraphs that modify the hash. One is at the beginning and the other at the very end. The rest is just the load function. Yes I tried to modify the sitemap for the first post but since the _escaped_fragment_ isn't implemented there is no effect by now.

Comment: This is JavaScript. To support this stuff you need some coding on server-side (PHP). I believe some WordPress plugins should provide this already, but I'm not an expert in WordPress.

Comment: thx, you mean something like this? (see 2nd answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626439/how-do-i-make-my-ajax-content-crawlable-by-google?rq=1 
I'll dig around that. I'd rather work without plugin if this can be achieved with 2 or 3 lines of code. I'll probably learn something on the way.

Comment: Yes, I think 2-3 lines of PHP code may be suffice. If I understand your JS code correctly, in there you have a place where `load(post_link` is executed. You should look at PHP code, where these `post_link`'s landed, and add an `if` branch for _escaped_fragment_ processing (it should be similar to what the server does for `#!`).

Comment: Ok thank you Stan. You've already answered my question, maybe I'll start a new thread for the second part. But BTW my post_link are simple hrefs pointing to `the_permalink();`... Do you mean I should create this `if` statement in those hrefs? If you have a little time, I can let you know once I created the new thread.

Comment: I've started the new thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844012/ajax-indexing-how-to-handle-escaped-fragment-request-with-php)  If you are fluent in php, I'd appreciate any help.